# Simple way to rename GRUB2 entries

Tags: grub2

I have many different Ubuntu versions installed on my HD. I'd like to rename some of their entries in GRUB2 boot menu. I have tried two approaches.

1. As described in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1347756). This is not working; I have 9 different lines with SDA11 sections visible in my 30_os-prober file. Am I supposed to modify all of them while in real boot menu only one entry for this partition is visible after `sudo update-grub`?
2. I have also tried the Grub Customizer application, but it just overpopulates my boot menu with duplicate entries.

Instead of doing it the hard way by modifying all the entries visible in 30_os-prober file, I would like to know if there is an easy solution? I may be overlooking something, but if there is no easier way, is this supposed to be harder than with GRUB1 for a reason?

Comment: Grub Customizer is supposed to be the way to go. Perhaps something went wrong while you were using it? It does exactly what you want. Try simply disabling the entries you don't use or need.

Comment: have you try [Grub Customizer 3.0 Released](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html) which brings the following new features entries can be moved free now,integrated settings dialog, new partition chooser, context menu, multi selection, trash instead of checkboxes, entry editor, graphical error handling, reset functionality, warning when trying to remove script - or system entries.

Comment: Yes, my Grub Customizer version was 3.0.2. The funny thing is that I newly installed Ubuntu on /dev/sda11, but I have never logged in yet. It's not like there are 9 old kernels hanging around, so I don't really even understand why did those 9 entries show up for sda11.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, all the files that include grub option **names** and all the options for editing and renaming are in the directory `/etc/grub.d/`

The 30_os_prober script could be modified to make them different. I prefer having better control using the generated configuration and disabling os_prober. It's not too hard to copy and paste items from the generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` into your own 40_custom or other files loaded in numerical order.

The file for options is at `/etc/default/grub`

I don't understand why you would have 11 entries in one partition. An example grub.cfg section might help to understand how to edit `30_os_prober` to your needs. Some details of what it looks like now (one big submenu?) and what you would like to see instead would help know how to edit the code.

To update grub run `update-grub`, generating the new file.

This [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) has lots of details and links.

Comment: I think it should be /etc/grub.d/